# How can I XOR wchar_t input, write it to a file, and read it back in C?

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

I have problem working with unicode strings, wchar_t type.

In my program I'm getting input as wchar_t and I'm supposed to XOR it and write it to file and read it back and print it to command line.

This is my code,

```
const unsigned int XORKey = 0xff;



size_t XORit(const wchar_t* value, wchar_t* xorred)
{
    size_t length = wcslen(value);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        xorred[i] = ((char)(value[i] ^ XORKey));

    return length;
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    // XOR it
    wchar_t sample[] = { L"TEST1自己人" };
    int samplelen = wcslen(sample);
    printf("%ls", sample);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Plain:\n\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < samplelen; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X ", sample[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");



    wchar_t* xorred = (wchar_t*)malloc(samplelen);
    if (xorred == NULL) return -1;
    memset(xorred, 0, samplelen);
    XORit(sample, xorred);
    printf("XOR'ed\n\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < samplelen; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X ", xorred[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Write to file
    FILE* fpW = _wfopen(L"logon.bin", L"wb");
    fwrite(xorred, sizeof(wchar_t), samplelen, fpW);
    fclose(fpW);


    // Read from file
    FILE* fpR = fopen("logon.bin", "rb");
    fseek(fpR, 0, SEEK_END);
    int filesize = ftell(fpR);
    wchar_t* unxorred = (wchar_t*)malloc(filesize + sizeof(wchar_t));
    if (unxorred == NULL) return -1;

    rewind(fpR);

    fread(unxorred, sizeof(wchar_t), filesize, fpW);
    fclose(fpW);

    printf("Reading\n\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < samplelen; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X ", unxorred[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Un-XOR'ed\n\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < samplelen; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X ", unxorred[i] ^ XORKey);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%ls", unxorred);

    return 0;
}
```

The values I'm reading back from the file doesn't match to what I wrote! :(
I'm new to C programming, I did my best to get this right, please forgive any noob mistakes in my understanding of the issue and implementing it.

Thanks in advance

I fixed the code based on the comments,

```
const unsigned int XORKey = 0xff;



size_t XORit(const wchar_t* value, wchar_t* xorred)
{
    size_t length = wcslen(value);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        xorred[i] = (value[i] ^ XORKey);

    return length;
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    // XOR it
    wchar_t sample[] = { L"Test1自己人自己人A" };
    int samplelen = wcslen(sample);
    printf("%ls", sample);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Plain:\n\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < samplelen; i++)
    {
        printf("%0*X ", (int)sizeof(wchar_t), (unsigned int)sample[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");



    wchar_t* xorred = (wchar_t*)malloc(samplelen);
    if (xorred == NULL) return -1;
    memset(xorred, 0, samplelen);
    XORit(sample, xorred);
    printf("XOR'ed\n\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < samplelen; i++)
    {
        printf("%0*X ", (int)sizeof(wchar_t), (unsigned int)xorred[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Write to file
    FILE* fpW = _wfopen(L"logon.bin", L"wb");
    fwrite(xorred, sizeof(wchar_t), samplelen, fpW);
    fclose(fpW);


    // Read from file
    FILE* fpR = fopen("logon.bin", "rb");
    fseek(fpR, 0, SEEK_END);
    int filesize = ftell(fpR);
    int whattoread = (filesize / sizeof(wchar_t));
    wchar_t* ReadXOR = (wchar_t*)malloc(filesize + 1);
    if (ReadXOR == NULL) return -1;
    memset(ReadXOR, 0, filesize + 1);

    rewind(fpR);

    fread(ReadXOR, sizeof(wchar_t), whattoread, fpR);
    fclose(fpW);

    printf("Reading\n\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < samplelen; i++)
    {
        printf("%0*X ", (int)sizeof(wchar_t), (unsigned int)ReadXOR[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");


    wchar_t* unxorred = (wchar_t*)malloc(whattoread);
    if (unxorred == NULL) return -1;
    memset(unxorred, 0, whattoread);
    printf("Un-XOR'ed\n\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < whattoread; i++)
    {
        unxorred[i] = ReadXOR[i] ^ 0xff;
        printf("%0*X ", (int)sizeof(wchar_t), (unsigned int)unxorred[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%ls\n", unxorred);
    printf("%ls\n", sample);
    

    return 0;
```

The output looks like below,

```
Test1自己人自己人A
Plain:
        54 65 73 74 31 81EA 5DF1 4EBA 81EA 5DF1 4EBA 41
XOR'ed
        AB 9A 8C 8B CE 8115 5D0E 4E45 8115 5D0E 4E45 BE
Reading
        AB 9A 8C 8B CE 8115 5D0E 4E45 8115 5D0E 4E45 BE
Un-XOR'ed
        54 65 73 74 31 81EA 5DF1 4EBA 81EA 5DF1 4EBA 41
Test1自己人自己人A粘蹊?言?萉?
Test1自己人自己人A
```

When I modified the unicode string I got wrong text in the output!

Comment: Why the cast? Just `xorred[i] = value[i] ^ XORKey;` Since you have `wchar_t` for the input and the output I'm not sure why you are casting to `char`.

Comment: First please decide what language you're actually program in. Don't tag multiple different languages, only the one you're actually program in. Then please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `(wchar_t*)malloc(samplelen)` should be `malloc(samplelen * sizeof(wchar_t))`

Comment: Im sorry for confusion, I would like to do it in C.

Comment: David, Size to the referenced object rather than type and avoid mistakes `wchar_t* xorred = (wchar_t*)malloc(samplelen + sizeof(wchar_t));` --> `wchar_t* xorred = malloc(sizeof xorred * (samplelen + 1));`

Comment: When you read the data back from the file, you do not allocate space for a (wide) string terminator, nor do you add one to the result.

Comment: And, if your `wchar_t` has size greater than 1 then you attempt to read back more data than the file contains.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ...

```
    printf("Un-XOR'ed\n\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < samplelen; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X ", unxorred[i] ^ XORKey);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

... you print out the decoded values *without storing them*.

When you then ...

```
    printf("%ls", unxorred);
```

... you are printing the data as read back from the file, *not* the decoded string corresponding to the previously-printed code sequence.

Additionally,

- here ...

  ```
      int filesize = ftell(fpR);
      wchar_t* unxorred = (wchar_t*)malloc(filesize);
      if (unxorred == NULL) return -1;

      rewind(fpR);

      fread(unxorred, sizeof(wchar_t), filesize, fpW);
  ```

  ... you are attempting to read back `sizeof(wchar_t) * filesize` bytes from the file, which is more than it actually contains or that you have allocated for (unless `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 1, which is possible, but unlikely, and is anyway not *your* case).
- You do not allocate space for a (wide) string terminator or add one to the read-back data, yet you pass it to `printf()` is if it were a wide string.  This is erroneous.
- Your approach to printing out the bytes of the wide strings is flawed.  The conversion specifier `X` requires a corresponding `unsigned int` argument, and `wchar_t` might neither be the same as `unsigned int` nor promote to `unsigned int` via the default argument promotions.  Additionally, you get varying-length outputs because your `wchar_t` is at least 16 bits wide, and your `02` only guarantees 2 hex digits.  Better would be, for example:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < samplelen; i++) {
      printf("%0*X ", (int) sizeof(wchar_t), (unsigned int) xorred[i]);
  }
  ```

  The `*` for a width says that the minimum field width will be passed as an argument of type `int`.  The casts match the arguments to the types required by the format.

Comment: Im reading and re-reading your answer, but there are few points I cannot figure out.
"... you are attempting to read back sizeof(wchar_t) * filesize bytes from the file, which is more than it actually contains or that you have allocated for unless sizeof(wchar_t) is 1 (which is possible, but unlikely)."
How should I change the fread() call?
Can you please kindly fix the code and post it here?

Comment: @David, `fread(unxorred, sizeof(wchar_t), filesize, fpW);` attempts to read `filesize` items, each of size `sizeof(wchar_t)`.  You have computed `filesize` as the number of *bytes* in the file, but your `wchar_t`s are larger than 1 byte each.  I'm sure you can figure it out from there.

Comment: so `(filesize / sizeof(wchar_t))? That seem to work for me, just want to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong/

Comment: so `(filesize / sizeof(wchar_t))? That seem to give me the correct output for wchar_t sample[] = { L"TEST1自己人" }; but if I change that to wchar_t sample[] = { L"Test1自己人自己人A" }; I still get some extra characters in my printf("%ls", unxorred);

Comment: I modified the code in the question(the one modified based on comments) and I tried to show how i get wrong text back.

Comment: Problem solved! I added a null terminator and to unxorred and everything is fine now. Thanks everyone for your helps.